# How to filter nested hash in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 4 application I have a (non-ActiveRecord) model containing the `plans` that a user can subscribe to:

```
class Plan

  PLANS = {
    'free'            => { :name => "Free",     :amount => 0,     :interval => '',   :maximum => FREE_MAXIMUM },
    'basic_monthly'   => { :name => "Basic",    :amount => 500,   :interval => 'month', :maximum => BASIC_MAXIMUM },
    'basic_yearly'    => { :name => "Basic",    :amount => 5000,  :interval => 'year',  :maximum => BASIC_MAXIMUM },
    'premium_monthy'  => { :name => "Premium",  :amount => 1000,  :interval => 'month', :maximum => PREMIUM_MAXIMUM },
    'premium_yearly'  => { :name => "Premium",  :amount => 10000, :interval => 'year',  :maximum => PREMIUM_MAXIMUM }
  }

  def self.all
    ...
  end

  def self.all_payable
    ...
  end

  def self.by_interval(interval)
    ...
  end

end
```

I have worked with ActiveRecord a lot but in this case I don't know how to filter the hash values so I can render them out to the front end.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def pricing
    @plans = Plan.all
  end

end
```

How can this be done?

Maybe my approach is entirely wrong and it's easier to store the plans in an array?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what filters are you trying to apply. Please supply output examples. by the way I think the methods you want are `Enumerable#find_all` or `Enumerable#select` and then in the block use standard `Hash` access methods

Answer (score 1):

An array or a hash would work for this. If I understand you correctly, your methods should look something like this.

```
def self.all
  # returns the entire PLANS hash
  PLANS
end

def self.all_payable
  # only return hash elements that are not free
  PLANS.find_all { |k,v| v[:name] != 'Free' }
end

def self.by_interval(interval)
  # return all elements where the :interval matches interval
  PLANS.find_all { |k,v| v[:interval] == interval }
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I think I am pretty close to what I need now. The only problem is that I get errors like `undefined method 'name' for #<Array:0x00000101a47308>` when trying to use these methods on the front end like I used to with ActiveRecord. Will I have to convert them to an `ActiveRecord::Relation` or something similar maybe?

Comment: well there is no `name` method there. The way your are doing it you are pretty much going to have to rewrite functionality that exists in active record.